# Inaccessible global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is definitely driving me crazy.

jQuery notifies me this message `[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]` when I try to retrieve the variable `$venusThumbDiv` inside the `collector()` function. In other words, I guess jQuery doesn't find any `$('.venus-thumb-div')` inside the page (althought there are four divs with that class).

What's incredible is that in the snippet below the code works exactly as it should but the **identical** piece of code doesn't work if I write it in the editor and run it on the same browser!! The only way to let it work "offline" is decommenting the var declaration inside the `collector()` function, but obviously it's totally useless 'cause I need the var `$venusThumbDiv` to be global.

Has anyone any clue on why I'm having this problem?

```js
var venusGallery = function () {

    var $venusThumbDiv              = $('.venus-thumb-div');

    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       PUBLIC FNS       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     collector()    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    var collector = function () {
        // var $venusThumbDiv              = $('.venus-thumb-div');
        console.log("Div number: " + $venusThumbDiv.length);
        console.log($venusThumbDiv); 
    };

    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     setOpts()    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    var setOpts = function (choosen_options) {
        var options = {
            progression:    '<div id="venus-progression" style="color: white"></div>',
            share:          '<div id="venus-share"></div>',
            fullscreen:     '<div id="venus-fullscreen"></div>',
            download:       '<div id="venus-download"></div>',
            description:    '<p id="venus-description"></p>'
        };

        /* Default: no options; options are showed only if declared and set to true in venusGallery.setOpts({}); */
        $.each(options, function (key, value) {
            if (choosen_options[key]) {
                options[key] = value;
            } else {                                    // if false or not declared: not showed
                options[key] = '';
            }
        });

        venusOpts = options;
    };
    /* *****************************************************************************************************************
     * ************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       PUBLIC FNS DEFINITION       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    /* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ */
    return {
        setOpts: setOpts,
        collector: collector
    };
    /* *****************************************************************************************************************
     * ************************************************************************************************************** */

}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="venus-gallery">

    <div class="venus-thumb-div" data-image="../img/bv.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/bv_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-thumb-div" data-image="../img/islamuj.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/islamuj_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-thumb-div" data-image="../img/vertical.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/vertical_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-thumb-div" data-image="../img/pano.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/pano_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        venusGallery.setOpts({
            progression: true,
            download: true,
            share: true,
            fullscreen: true
        });
        venusGallery.collector();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did it and it prints: 0

Comment: In that case, yes, the element is not found when you execute your jQuery. Is the element appended to the page dynamically after load? Via AJAX for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, it's into the HTML page since the beginning, that's why it's driving me crazy. Having any clue I even tried to load the same jQuery version that StackOverflow uses in its snippets but the result, "offline", is always 0!